# Can I step through the source of my IIS 7 deployed MVC app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging, iis, visual-studio-debugging

I'd like to step through the source code of my MVC application that I just deployed locally on an IIS 7 server. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

In VS 2010, go to - `Solution Explorer->Right Click Your Application->Go to Properties->Select Web Tab`

And Select **Use Local IIS Webserver** and specify the Project Url.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open your project in Visual Studio. Publish your application with all the debug files to IIS. 
After that, go to the Debug menu a click attach to process. Find the process of your IIS site and attach it.

Also search google for Remote Debugger. It is a tool of Microsoft for those kind of perposes. I'm not sure if you need Ultimate for that

Comment: Thank you. That's very interesting. I will try that out as well.